# Magento add Flexslider to homepage

Tags: php, jquery, magento, flexslider, bitnami

I am using the `Bitnami Magento` https://bitnami.com/stack/magento stack and trying to add [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)to the homepage.  I'm getting this error in my `custom.js` file:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'flexslider'
```

for the Home Page I've added this to the `CMS->Pages->Design-Custom Layout Design XML`

```
<reference name="head"> 
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/flexslider.css</stylesheet></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.min.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>flexslider/custom.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

All the scripts are loading I've verified with the browser debugger console

This is the `custom.js` script

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
```

This is in `CMS->Pages->Content` for the homepage

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="Big.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="Big1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="Big2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Another interesting thing is that when I change the `Custom Theme` on the page design to anything else besides the `rwd default` it will load the slider correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slider that comes with the `RWD` theme and I am using that now.  This article explains how to use it.

http://www.creare.co.uk/new-features-magento-ce-1-9-responsive-theme#slider

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmiM4oWGrLI and got it to work on my site. Your approach seems sound so I suspect there's some sort of conflict with rwd default. Have you Firebuged it to eliminate conflicting classes/ids?